# Stability of the unit interval under the binary operation $x*y=x+y-xy$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, real-numbers, binary-operations

Let $I=[0,1]$ the unit interval. I want to show that If $x\in [0,1]$ and $y\in [0,1]$ then $x+y-xy\in [0,1]$

My first attempt is to write $x+y-xy= (1-y)x+y.1$ which is a point in the segment $[x,1]$ since $[x,1]$ is convex. Hence $x+y-xy\in I$.

My second attempt is to use a direct method without mentioning the notion of convexity: we have that $x-xy=x(1-y)\geq 0$ so $x\geq xy$ and similarly $y\geq xy$
hence $x+y\geq xy$ so $x+y-xy\geq 0$. But I don't see how to show that $xy-xy\leq 1$.

Comment: Can't you just test endpoints? Find $\sup \{x+y-xy\}$ and $\inf \{x+y -xy\} : x,y \in [0,1]$?

Comment: Palio's second attempt already shows that $\text{inf} \{x+y-xy\}\ge 0$. As for checking the $\text{sup}$, consider your first attempt: $x+y-xy=(1-y)x+y$, and see if you can find an $x$ such that the expression $(1-y)x+y$ is maximized.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Write $x+y-xy$ as $1-(1-x)(1-y)$. Now note that $1-x,1-y \in [0,1]$ and conclude what you want.

Comment: Thank you, is what i find here correct : for the law $x*y=x+y-xy$, No element other than zero is invertible, and that all elements $a\in [0,1]$ ,except $1$, are regular (in the sense that $a*b=a*c$ implies $b=c$)?

Answer (score 5):

[image: point in unit square]

You can use geometry too. There's a unit square. Assume point D has coordinates $(x,y)$, so D locates inside (or on the borders of) this unit square.

Notice that $x=area(OGEF)$, $y=area(OABC)$, $xy=area(OGDC)$, and the unit square's area is 1, we get 
$$
0 \leq x+y-xy \leq 1
$$